# Why when I use touchstart event is not fired after scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, events, mobile, fixed

I have attached a touchstart event to my fixed positioned footer in a web-app

so the structure is like this:

```
<div id="content">i am a looong content.</div>
<div id="footer">i am tappable!</div>
```

and the code like this:

```
$("#footer").on('touchstart', function(e) { alert("tapped"); });
```

The problem is that when I scroll down the page to read the (long) content, the `touchstart` event for my footer just stops working! it does not get called anymore.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

Here is my exact scenario:

http://contoso2.azurewebsites.net/quiz/testing

Using an iPad, if you scroll down, the buttons in the footer are not fired.

Comment: silly question, have u tried with `touchend`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but do the same behavior

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey how come do you think touchend will work while touchstart doesn't?